# Define type as "all possibilities from an enum" in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following enum

```
export enum USER_GROUPS {
  "Admin",
  "Design",
  "FrontEnd",
  "BackEnd"
}
```

And the following function

```
const isUserOfType = (userGroupId: number, userType: USER_GROUPS) => {
  return userGroupId === USER_GROUPS[userType];
};
```

Where

```
isUserOfType(2, "Design") // returns true
isUserOfType(1, "BackEnd") // returns false
```

The problem is the second param is not assignable to `type: USER_GROUPS`... I could do the following

```
isUserOfType = (
    userGroupId: number,
    userType:
      | USER_GROUPS.Admin
      | USER_GROUPS.Design
      | USER_GROUPS.FrontEnd
      | USER_GROUPS.BackEnd
  ) => {
      return userGroupId === USER_GROUPS[userType];
    };
```

However, that is annoying to do on every function. and defining a completely separate type defeats some of the purpose of an enum

Comment: @jcalz it says `"Design" is not assignable to USER_GROUPS`

Comment: I don’t get why you’re doing that union then... the thing you call “possible but annoying” shouldn’t work either. You might be looking for `keyof typeof USER_GROUPS` but I’m on mobile right now so not in a great position to help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use `keyof typeof` to get all the Enum keys:

```
export enum USER_GROUPS {
  "Admin",
  "Design",
  "FrontEnd",
  "BackEnd"
}

type USER_GROUPS_KEYS = keyof typeof USER_GROUPS;

const isUserOfType = (userGroupId: number, userType: USER_GROUPS_KEYS) => {
  return userGroupId === USER_GROUPS[userType];
};

isUserOfType(2, "Design") // returns true
isUserOfType(1, "BackEnd") // returns false
```

Personally I would use string enums or a string union type instead:

```
export enum USER_GROUPS_V2 {
  "Admin" = "Admin",
}

export type USER_GROUPS_UNION_TYPE = 
  | "Admin"
  | "Design";
```

but if you're stuck with another data source that requires these to be numerical, then the above will work.